# U-Boot add node to devicetree during startup

Tags: c, driver, u-boot, device-tree

I work on a custom board with a Cyclone V SoC.

I need to add some informations to U-Boot device tree at startup and these informations are stored in an I2C device.

It appears that U-Boot device tree is read-only during its execution but before relocation. The function `board_fix_fdt (void *rw_fdt_blob)` can be used to make changes on the device tree before relocation.

The problem I have is that I cannot access the I2C device at this time. The driver doesn't seem to be loaded yet.

Can someone give me any hints on how I can enable the I2C at this stage ?

U-Boot version is 2018-05.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add in u-boot device tree the i2c driver and also the reset driver for pre-relocation states :

```
&rst {
    status = "okay";
    u-boot,dm-pre-reloc;  // HERE
};

&i2c2 {
    status = "okay";
    u-boot,dm-pre-reloc;   // and HERE
}
```